# How to receive json data response when call web API success?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

I work on asp.net razor page Login user name and password . I call Web API validate user

name and password . my issue I face I can't deserialize data response returned after login success

JSON data returned from web API after success login username and password

```
{
    "message": "success",
    "status": true,
    "data": {
        "userID": "9595",
        "userName": "ADC Test User",
        "userRole": "Administrator",
        "environment": "PY"
    },
    "statusCode": "0000"
}
```

I call API from razor page login as below :

```
public async Task OnPost()
{

           
            UserLoginViewModel loginview = new UserLoginViewModel();
            loginview.UserID = User.UserName;
            loginview.Password = User.vPassword;
            var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(loginview);
            var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://localhost:44374/api/adcxx/ValidateUser");
            request.Content = content;
            var response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(request);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
          

             
            }
}
```

I need to deserialize returned data from login success where `message=success` as logic below :

```
 if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
IF(message=="success" AND status="true")
{
receive `user id and username and user role and password`
}
}
```

image below explain what I need to do exactly

[image: image show data I need to receive]

**How to deserialize data from `var response` to get details data as
message,status,userid and username and user role and environment ?**

Comment: can any one help me solving issues above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the follwoing code.

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class adcxx : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

        public adcxx(HttpClient httpClient)
        {
            this._httpClient = httpClient;
        }

        [HttpGet("ValidateUser")]
        public IActionResult ValidateUser()
        {
            return new JsonResult(new { message = 1, status = true, data = new {userID=9595,userName= "ADC Test User",userRole= "Administrator", environment="PY" },statusCode=0000 }); 
        }

        [HttpGet("test")]
        public async Task OnPost()
        {

            HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://localhost:7215/api/adcxx/ValidateUser");
            var response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(request);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var jsonResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();            
                var jobject = JObject.Parse(jsonResponse);

                var message = jobject["message"];
                var status = jobject["status"];
                var userID = jobject["data"]["userID"];
                var userName = jobject["data"]["userName"];
                var userRole = jobject["data"]["userRole"];
                var environment = jobject["data"]["environment"];
                var statusCode = jobject["statusCode"];

                Console.WriteLine(jobject);
                Console.WriteLine(message);
                Console.WriteLine(status);
                Console.WriteLine(userID);
                Console.WriteLine(userName);
                Console.WriteLine(userRole);
                Console.WriteLine(environment);
                Console.WriteLine(statusCode);
            }
        }
    }
```

Test output from /api/adcxx/test
[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
var jsonResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Above line will give json string. In your case like below :

```
    {
        "message": "success",
        "status": true,
        "data": {
            "userID": "9595",
            "userName": "ADC Test User",
            "userRole": "Administrator",
            "environment": "PY"
        },
        "statusCode": "0000"
    }
```

Further you can desterilize this json in c# class, for that purpose create one class for example named UserAuthResponse like below (according to your response)

```
    public class UserAuthResponse 
    {
       [JsonPropertyName("message")]
       public string Message { get; set; };
       [JsonPropertyName("status")]
       public string Status { get; set; }; 
       [JsonPropertyName("data")]
       public UserData Data { get; set; };
       [JsonPropertyName("statusCode")]
       public int StatusCode { get; set; };
    }
    
    public class UserData
    {
       [JsonPropertyName("userID")]
       public long UserID { get; set; }; 
       [JsonPropertyName("userName")]
       public string UserName { get; set; };
       [JsonPropertyName("userRole")]
       public string UserRole { get; set; };
       [JsonPropertyName("environment")]
       public string Environment { get; set; };
    }
```

For deserialization you can do

```
    UserAuthResponse? userAuthResponse = 
                    JsonSerializer.Deserialize(jsonResponse);
```

Then after you can do

```
    if(userAuthResponse is not null)
    {
      if(userAuthResponse.Message == "success" && userAuthResponse.Status)
      {
        .....
      }
    }
```

For further better understanding please read below official docs from MS

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/networking/http/httpclient
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/how-to?pivots=dotnet-8-0